# Node.js on('end') stream's listener fires twice

Tags: node.js

It's a ordinary node practice, the on("end") callback fires twice per request even with using readable.once("end"). Here's tha code:

```
require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
     var readable = require("fs").createReadStream("./image.jpg",{highWaterMark:1024*1024});
     readable.on("data", function (data) {
         res.write(data);
     })

    readable.on("end", function () {
        res.end()
        console.log("Ended");
    })

}).listen(9000, function () {
    console.log("Listening.... on 9000");
});
```

Comment: So that would mean two requests are being handled.

Comment: NOpe, It's just one request.

Comment: If it triggers twice when using `.once()`, the only reasonable explanation would be that there are two requests being handled. Try adding `console.log(req.url)` to the request handler.

Comment: I've tested it again and found that it fires twice only in refreshing tha page, but if I requested it in a new tab, it runs well .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 requests being sent whenever you request the page one for the main directory " / " and the other for the "favicon.ico" , so that why the function fires twice, in order to solve that put an if condition for the req.url and spacify the directory you want and it will work.

Comment: @robertklep Check this out.

Comment: @BaHaaJr. like I said :D